# spring boot container not running because of dependancy on postgres container

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, docker

I have one postgres container and one spring boot container. I am running both of them using docker-compose.

Below is the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    restart: always
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/testDb
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
  postgres-db:
    working_dir: /home/models
    image: postgres:11.3-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=testDb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Here's the `Dockerfile.dev`

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

ENV HOME=/home/usr/app

RUN mkdir -p $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

ADD pom.xml $HOME

RUN ["/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh", "mvn", "dependency:go-offline"]

ADD . $HOME

RUN ["mvn", "package"]

CMD ["java","-jar","/usr/app/testApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and here's the `application.properties` file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres-db:5432/testDb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

but when I run the containers using `docker-container up` I am getting the error saying the connection to database failed and the container stops.

**Edit:**
I have added the following `db-check.sh` file for checking the status of db

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until PGPASSWORD="password" psql -h "$host" -U "root" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done


>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

and the new `Dockerfile.dev` looks like:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-8

ENV HOME=/home/usr/app

RUN mkdir -p $HOME

WORKDIR $HOME

ADD db-check.sh $HOME

RUN chmod +x db-check.sh

RUN ["./db-check.sh", "postgres-db:5432", "/usr/local/bin/mvn-entrypoint.sh", "mvn", "dependency:go-offline"]

ADD . $HOME

RUN ["mvn", "package"]

CMD ["java","-jar","/usr/app/testApp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

but for this script to run successfully I need psql installed in the backend container. Is there any other way of checking this because if feel that I am putting a lot of things in this single backend container for the sake of just checking the status of postgres container.

Comment: Looks like your java container is started before postgres is fully launched. Have a look at [Control startup and shutdown order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: So `depends_on` parameter won't work alone on it's own and I need to add a supporter script @michalk?

Comment: `depends_on` only makes sure that container is started before the others - it does not necesairly mean it is ready to accept connections.

Comment: The documentation link cleared my doubts. Thanks!

Comment: @michalk I have edited the question with some more doubts. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, probably the `postgres-db` container is not ready yet, because it has to initialzed at first run.

As a cheap workaround you can do this:

1. Start postgres-db container only: `$ docker-compose up -d postgres-db`
2. Wait a moment (let's say 10-20 sec)
3. `$ docker-compose up -d --build`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah this solution works and I was using this earlier but I want a more automated way which will also help in the deployment phase.